# Qt objects can still be deletedLater() without event loop?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm confused about threads and event loops in Qt.

A [QThread](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html) normally runs `exec()` in `run()`. But when you override `run()`, there will not be an event loop.

[This (older) doc](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.2/threads.html) states that calling `deleteLater()` on objects that are created in a thread without an event loop doesn't work:

> If no event loop is running, events won't be delivered to the object.
>   For example, if you create a QTimer object in a thread but never call
>   exec(), the QTimer will never emit its timeout() signal. Calling
>   deleteLater() won't work either. (These restrictions apply to the main
>   thread as well.)

However, look at the following code:

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QString content;

public:
    MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyObject();
};

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:

public slots:

};

MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    content("foobar")
{}

MyObject::~MyObject()
{
    // This code is still executed before I close the program. How?
    qDebug() << "Destroying MyObject";
}

MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{}

void MyThread::run()
{
    // Creating a heap object in a thread that does not have 
    // an event loop (because I reimplemented run()).
    MyObject * objectification = new MyObject();
    sleep(1);
    objectification->deleteLater();
}
```

So why does the `deletelater()` call still post an event that is picked up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [Qt docs state for deleteLater](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater): -

> Since Qt 4.8, if deleteLater() is called on an object that lives in a thread with no running event loop, the object will be destroyed when the thread finishes.

The object is still being deleted when no event loop exists. If you look at the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp) for QObject::deleteLater, you'll see that an event is posted:-

```
void QObject::deleteLater()
{
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QDeferredDeleteEvent());
}
```

So, let's look at what happens [when a thread is deleted](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/0aca5cf05288dc4d2175d1c4a78bf62a5ea96b21%3asrc/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp#LNaN-NaN). QThreadData's destructor includes this:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < postEventList.size(); ++i) {
    const QPostEvent &pe = postEventList.at(i);
    if (pe.event) {
        --pe.receiver->d_func()->postedEvents;
        pe.event->posted = false;
        delete pe.event;
    }
}
```

As we see, although there's no event loop, the event list is still available.

If we look more closely into [QThreadPrivate](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt-rauls-clone/source/a43583e0221311b7fe666726ab668e41c5e4bba2%3asrc/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp#L327) (just taking one platform as an example, in this case unix), you'll see that when the thread finishes, it forwards all deferred deleted messages, so they can continue to be processed:

```
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(0, QEvent::DeferredDelete);
```

Comment: I also noticed that if you call code that does signal/slot processing, it still works, even if there is no event loop. For example, if you create a `QNetworkManager` inside the above thread and make a request and such, and have the thread wait until it's done, all slots get processed. I expected they wouldn't. (I know this is not how you're supposed to use threads, because it's synchronous programming in a thread. It's merely as an example.)

Comment: Where are you creating the QNetworkManager? Is it in the constructor of the inherited QThread and does it have a parent?

Comment: It would be created in `void run()`, and the parent is another object created in `void run()`.

Comment: When a signal is sent, if the thread affinity of the receiving object is the same as from where the event is being sent, a direct connection is used and there is no need to post the event. The call is instantaneous and no event loop is required. See connect connection types: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum